# Windows Worker Service Error- A timeout was reached, service to connect

Tags: c#, windows-services, visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-6.0

I have created a windows worker service. But the service is timing out while starting up. To troubleshoot the issue, I have created a service without implementing anything funtionality.

The service is running as a Local System account, but I am getting the same error. I have added the below registry entry, but it didn't help. I am not sure how suddenly I am getting this issue.

```
ServicesPipeTimeout = 180000
```

Worker.cs

```
namespace MyService
{
  public class Worker : BackgroundService
  {
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
 }
```

}

Program.cs

```
using MyService;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices;

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
       .UseWindowsService()
       .Build();

       await host.RunAsync();
```

Comment: Have you added `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices` nuget and called something like `services.AddWindowsService(opts => opts.ServiceName = "ServiceName")`?

Comment: I have added my program.cs file. Yes, its there.

Comment: Was not able to reproduce, works just fine (though reduced the delay for graceful shutdown). How do you install the service? Also why is this tagged with ASP.NET Core?

Comment: I installed using the command: sc.exe create NewService binpath= c:\windows\system32\NewServ.exe type= share start= auto

Comment: Very strange. Can you please post a full repro somewhere?